# Cordova plugin for waking up the application for webrtc call

Tags: javascript, cordova, webrtc, cordova-plugins, hybrid-mobile-app

I have created a cordova app for video calls using the twilio video sdk. I use websockets to open a call dialog when the app is in foreground and push notifications when the app is in background. However, a push notification is not enough for the user to answer a video call. I would like a plugin to wake up the application even if it is killed and bring it to foreground like viber/messenger/skype do. Is there a plugin or a way to achieve that?

Comment: Please, how have you solved this?